# Thawing Lambda functions doesn't decrease latency

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm using `serverless-warmup-plugin` to run a cron that invokes a Lambda function every 10 minutes. The code for the Lambda function looks like this:

```
exports.lambda = (event, context, callback) => {
    if (event.source === 'serverless-plugin-warmup') {
        console.log('Thawing lambda...')
        callback(null, 'Lambda is warm!')
    } else {
        // ... logic for the lambda function
    }
}
```

This works on paper but in practice the cron doesn't keep the Lambda function warm even though it successfully invokes it every 10 minutes.

When the Lambda is invoked via a different event source (other than the cron) it takes around 2-3 seconds for the code to execute. Once it's executed  this way, Lambda actually warms up and starts responding under 400ms. And it stays warm for a while.

What am I missing here?

Comment: 10 minutes? I guess in 10 minutes with no activity is enough for a lambda container to cooldown. Did you try to decrease to 5 or 3 minutes for example?

Comment: Did you also check with cloudwatch events? (like a cron to execute). As Tom, said 10 minutes may be enough for the lambda to cool down. 
Was reading this just now 
https://medium.com/build-acl/aws-lambda-deployment-with-terraform-24d36cc86533

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to the frequency of the cron because even when I invoke the function 10 seconds after cron invokes it, it still goes through a cold start (3s response time), and the following invocation responds under 400ms. It's as if the invocation from the cron doesn't affect it all.

Comment: Check the cloud watch log for the lambda created by the plugin. You might not have added the permission to allow it to connect to your other lambdas.

Comment: The logs for the lambda that's created by the plugin is looking good, it has all the necessary IAM permissions and successfully invokes lambdas that it's supposed to. These successful invocations appear in the logs of targeted lambdas as well.

Comment: @cinnaroll45 Do the "warmup" logs appear in the same CloudWatch LogGroup as the normal invocations? You have to know that each LogGroup refers to a single container. If the warmup log appears together with the rest, then it's probably not a warm-up issue and maybe something about your handler itself.

Answer (score 1):

As the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction.html) states:

> **Note**
>
> When you write your Lambda function code, do not assume that AWS Lambda always reuses the container because AWS Lambda may choose not to reuse the container. Depending on various other factors, AWS Lambda may simply create a new container instead of reusing an existing container.

It seems like a "bad architecture design" to try to keep a Lambda Container up, but, apparently it's a normal scenario your warmed container not being used when a different event source triggers a new container.